# Imported iphone cannot be activated

Tags: ios, iphone

Recently I bought a used iphone 4s that was imported to Sweden. The problem is that I am not able to activate it, it only displays messages about how it tried to but failed. As a result I am getting the "No Service" banner and no connection to the carrier, Telia that I am trying to connect to.

I had however a brief moment of luck when I was able to get it "almost" activated and it connected to my carrier and allowed phone calls and texts but no data and since cellular data is very important for me I tried another system restore to get it working but unfortunately I cannot get the phone activated now again and I am stuck with the "No service" banner.

In the phone menu inside the settings I can still see the banner for "Sprint-services" could this be a cause of the problem?

Comment: is the phone Unlocked ? means freed from Sprint ? Did your "Telia" company give you a SIM card ?

Comment: Yes it is unlocked and I got a SIM card from Telia, which the phone accepts. I just cannot connect to 3G for some reason.

Comment: Does your phone shows Telia and full signal bar

Comment: No, no signal or Telia just No service. Going to take it to the Telia store later and let them have a look